# Any application to create images that contain text (like buttons)?

Tags: images, software-rec, editing

I am developing a blog and I want to put in title images like this:

[image]

Can anyone suggest good desktop application that does this? It shouldn't be difficult to use.

Comment: Quick note: What you want to do isn't considered good style. To [maintain accessibility](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG10-HTML-TECHS/) on your site, you should always add an alternative text to those images, consisting of the actual text. Actually, you don't want to use those at all. CSS can also [help you style buttons](http://www.cssbuttongenerator.com/) without the need for images (which are really hard to maintain).

Comment: Yes. You are right...right now i am doing the same..but you cant use CSS every time..[http://i40.tinypic.com/wummhj.jpg] i  cant get this effect using CSS..Thanks for commenting.

Comment: someone downvoted my answer, but check out http://www.imagemagick.org/script/convert.php for an example of programmatically generating those types of images

Comment: @Foon Bah: Thanks for the answer but your answer is quite irrelevant..i wont do PHP coding just for getting buttons..css is always better option...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you're using unusual fonts or styling, then you should be able to achieve button styling using [CSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascading_Style_Sheets).  This [CSS button designer](http://www.pagetutor.com/button_designer/index.html) should help if you're not familiar with CSS.

Comment: Great Link.Automatic CSS designer is Cool...but i am strictly looking for images.Thanx..

Comment: Thanks for the upvote - I guess something like Web Button Maker (http://www.antssoft.com/ultrabutton/index.htm) is what you're after - I haven't used any of this software though so unfortunately can't give a proper review or recommendation.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Paint.NET](http://www.getpaint.net/) to create the images you want, it's a free photoshop-like Windows app, but if you're on Mac OS I don't know any free app's besides GIMP, which is kind of gimpy.

Answer (score 1):

You can create buttons with CSS or images of buttons with graphics editing software like [Adobe Photoshop](http://www.adobe.com/products/photoshop.html) or [GIMP](http://www.gimp.org/), the latter of which is free. Either way, it can be very involved work in some cases. You might also consider having a professional graphic designer or web developer do it for you, if you're shorter on time than money.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into [Imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php)?  The convert tool can generate that button.

Comment: How does a conversion tool solve this issue?

Comment: I interpreted the question as how to create the button.  Have you looked at the convert tool?  the `-draw` flag lets you render text.  For example, look at http://www.imagemagick.org/script/convert.php